# SQL Query over three different tables

Tags: php, sql, mysql, join

i got three tables

```
CATS
id           name
------------------------------
1            category1
2            category2
3            category3
4            category4


PRODUCT
id           name
------------------------------
1            product1
2            product2



ZW-CAT-PRODUCT
id_cats      id_product
------------------------------
1            1
3            1
4            2
```

now i want to get my products and their categories

```
product1 => category1,category3
product2 => category4
```

is there a way to get this array (or object or something) with one mysql query?
i tried a bit with JOINS, but it seems thats this is not exactly what i need, or?

currently i'm using 3 querys (i think thats too much).

any suggestions?

### edit

and on the other way, what if i want to get ALL products of a specific category?
can this also be done in one query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [GROUP_CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) to get a separated list in your results.

```
SELECT p.*, 
       GROUP_CONCAT(c.name SEPARATOR ',') as cats
FROM PRODUCT p
LEFT JOIN ZW-CAT-PRODUCT l
  ON l.id_product=p.id
LEFT JOIN CATS c
  ON c.id=l.id_cats
GROUP BY p.id
```

So basically, this first does some joins to get all the data. If you were to replace the `GROUP_CONCAT` line with just `c.name`, you would see a row for each product_id/category pair. The `GROUP BY` tells it to group results based on product ID, and then `GROUP_CONCAT(c.name..)` is telling to it take all the different `c.name` values that occur in a group (so for each product ID, since you're grouping by product ID) and concatenate those values into one string, using `,` as the separator.

So to get all products for a each category in the same style, it would be like this,

```
SELECT c.*, 
       GROUP_CONCAT(p.name SEPARATOR ',') as products
FROM CATS c
LEFT JOIN ZW-CAT-PRODUCT l
  ON l.id_cats=c.id
LEFT JOIN PRODUCT p
  ON p.id=l.id_product
GROUP BY c.id
```

**EDIT:** To get just the product rows for a particular category (as requested in comment), it's this.

```
SELECT p.*
FROM PRODUCT p
LEFT JOIN ZW-CAT-PRODUCT l
  ON l.id_product=p.id
LEFT JOIN CATS c
  ON c.id=l.id_cats
WHERE c.name='xyz';
```

Comment: that worked, wow. even if i don't really know what i did ;) i have to get a deeper look into that. can you check my edit above?

Comment: I've updated my answer to try and explain a bit better what's going on, and shown how to flip this around to do the same for products, etc.

Comment: okay, thanks :) but getting all products of a category i dont want to get them comma seperated. just something like ´SELECT * FROM PRODUCTS WHERE CATEGORY = 'xyz'´. you know hat i mean? =/

Comment: In that case, it's just something like "SELECT p.*
FROM PRODUCT p
LEFT JOIN ZW-CAT-PRODUCT l
  ON l.id_product=p.id
LEFT JOIN CATS c
  ON c.id=l.id_cats
WHERE c.name='xyz';"

Answer (score 2):

If you need just comma-separated list of categories for every product, look at MySQL's [`GROUP_CONCAT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) aggregate function:

```
SELECT p.*, GROUP_CONCAT(c.name) AS categories
FROM PRODUCT p
LEFT JOIN ZW-CAT-PRODUCT cp ON p.id = cp.id_product
LEFT JOIN CATS c ON cp.id_cats = c.id
GROUP BY p.id
```

To get all products of a specific category (by category ID):

```
SELECT p.*
FROM PRODUCT p
INNER JOIN ZW-CAT-PRODUCT cp ON p.id = cp.id_product
WHERE cp.id_cats = 42
```

The same, but by category name:

```
SELECT p.*
FROM PRODUCT p
INNER JOIN ZW-CAT-PRODUCT cp ON p.id = cp.id_product
INNER JOIN CATS c ON cp.id_cats = c.id
WHERE c.name = 'category1'
```

Comment: I've updated the answer with the query for all products of a specific category

Comment: thank you too. poorly i cannot double accept an answer ;) but upvoted

Answer (score 1):

You could fit all 3 into 1 query yes, but consider having 3 huges tables, i'd rather process them one by one instead of getting the whole bulk back in 1 time.
This takes longer, but is (in my opinion) more data friendly.

Comment: i strongly agree with this, do one query on each table instead of trying to cram them all together, it will be more flexible and easier to parse through the results. I normally use the SQL IN statement to find children.